# How to properly join when comparing the difference between two tables pertaining to specific fields

Tags: sql-server, compare, temp-tables, join

I'm having problems writing this query. So I'm comparing a temp table to a table within our database. I want to find any records that don't have the same Case_Number the same Id_Number combination between the two table. The query I am using only provides me one or the other depending on how I join them. If I join by Case_Number, it returns the Case_Number records that do not match between the two tables. If I join by Id_Number, it will return the Id_Numbers that do not match between the two tables.. Is there a way to join by both Case_Number and ID_Number so that the query returns both? I would also like to know if it would be possible for me to include an "If Exist" to the query? Code below

```
 SELECT T1.Case_Number, T1.Id_Number, T1.FirstDate, T1.LastDate, T2.Case_Number, T2.Id_Number, T2.FirstDate, T2.LastDate
    FROM dbo.table T
    inner join #TempTable T2
     on T1.Id_Number = T2.Id_Number
    --on T1.Case_Number = T2.Case_Number
    where T1.LastDate is null
     and T1.Case_Number <> T2.Case_Number
     OR T1.Id_number <> T2.Id_Number
```

Comment: Please choose EITHER MySql or SqlServer - they have different syntax. Choose the one you use.

Comment: I think you need to look at left joins. And add some parenthesis in your where predicates or you are likely not going to have the logic correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should find both - firsst colum tells you what is the case

```
(
    SELECT 'in Table not in Temp' as R,
        T1.Case_Number as 'T1.Case_Number', 
        T1.Id_Number as 'T1.Id_Number', 
        T1.FirstDate as 'T1.FirstDate', 
        T1.LastDate as 'T1.LastDate', 
        null as 'T2.Case_Number', 
        null as 'T2.Id_Number', 
        null as 'T2.FirstDate', 
        null as 'T2.LastDate'
    FROM dbo.table T1 
    where not exists ( 
        select 1 
        from #TempTable T2 
        where T1.Case_Number == T2.CaseNumber
          and T1.Id_Number == T2.Id_Number)
) 
UNION ALL 
(
    SELECT 'in temp, not in list' as R
        null as 'T1.Case_Number', 
        null as 'T1.Id_Number',  
        null as 'T1.FirstDate',  
        null as 'T1.LastDate', 
        T2.Case_Number as 'T2.Case_Number',  
        T2.Id_Number as 'T2.Id_Number',  
        T2.FirstDate as 'T2.FirstDate',  
        T2.LastDate as 'T2.LastDate'
    FROM #TempTable T2 
    where not exists ( 
        select 1 
        from dbo.table T1 
        where T1.Case_Number == T2.CaseNumber
          and T1.Id_Number == T2.Id_Number )

)
```

Add the `T1.LastDate is null` - not sure where you want it.

You probably need to tweak the column names , I switched T1/T2 for 2nd statement so column will be the same table all the time, but names have duplicates.

Comment: This returns errors that state: multi-part identifier "field" could not be bound. For the first section of the query, the T2 fields could not be bound and for the second section of the query, the T1 fields could not be bound

Comment: @User812372 Youre right - I tried to correct it. You are no longer joining the tables (which makes no sense if the do not match at all) - therefor each statement does either know T1 or T2. Without a ddl of your both tables its kindof hard to write a valid dml select. The idea bedind is being: 1st statement gives you all from dbo.table that are only in it and dummy-coliumns for the other values, the second statement gives you all that are only in the #temtbl with dummycolums for T1 and the union all gives you all of them in one select. Did the other answer work for you?

Comment: The other answer did not work for me but I believe I might have found a way to make it work. I took my original query and placed it within yours. Both sections uses the same query, just joined differently. The first section of the query, I joined on case_number and the second section I joined on id_number. This returned both case_number and id_number mismatches at once

Answer (score 0):

Use `or` in `inner join` statement

```
SELECT T1.Case_Number,
       T1.Id_Number,
       T1.FirstDate,
       T1.LastDate,
       T2.Case_Number,
       T2.Id_Number,
       T2.FirstDate,
       T2.LastDate
FROM dbo.table T
INNER JOIN #TempTable T2 ON (T1.Id_Number = T2.Id_Number
                             OR T1.Case_Number = T2.Case_Number)
WHERE T1.LastDate IS NULL
  AND T1.Case_Number <> T2.Case_Number
  OR T1.Id_number <> T2.Id_Number
```